# Import classes via netbeans

Tags: java, class, methods

I have been trying to figure out where I have made my error.  I am new to java and am doing an introductory class.  Basically I have to create a countletterinanarray program, where I call a class I previously created.  I have tried to add the library to no avail and can't figure out how to get it to work.  The only error in the entire program I have received is cannot add import for randomcharacter.RandomCharacter.  Here is my code below:
package countlettersinarray;

```
/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class CountLettersInArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declare and create an array
        char[] chars = createArray();

        //Display the array
        System.out.println("The lowercase letters are:");
        displayArray(chars);

        //Count the occurences of each letter
        int[] counts = countLetters(chars);

        //Displahy counts
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The occurences of each letter are:");
        displayCounts(counts);        
    }

    /**Create an array of characters**/
    public static char[] createArray() {
        //Declare an array of characters and create it
        char[] chars = new char[100];

        //Create lower case letters randomly and assign
        //them to the array
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
            chars[i] = RandomCharacter.getRandomLowerCaseLetter();

        //Return the array
        return chars;
    }

    public static void displayArray(char[] chars) {
        //Display characters in the array 20 on each line
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) % 20 == 0)
                System.out.println(chars[i]);
            else 
                System.out.print(chars[i] + " ");
        }
    }
        /** Count the occurences of each letter*/
        public static int[] countLetters(char[] chars) {
            //Declare and create an array of 26 int
            int[] counts = new int[26];

            //For each lower case letter in the array, count it
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
                counts[chars[i] - 'a']++;

            return counts;package countlettersinarray;


/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class CountLettersInArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declare and create an array
        char[] chars = createArray();

        //Display the array
        System.out.println("The lowercase letters are:");
        displayArray(chars);

        //Count the occurences of each letter
        int[] counts = countLetters(chars);

        //Displahy counts
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The occurences of each letter are:");
        displayCounts(counts);        
    }

    /**Create an array of characters**/
    public static char[] createArray() {
        //Declare an array of characters and create it
        char[] chars = new char[100];

        //Create lower case letters randomly and assign
        //them to the array
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
            chars[i] = RandomCharacter.getRandomLowerCaseLetter();

        //Return the array
        return chars;
    }

    public static void displayArray(char[] chars) {
        //Display characters in the array 20 on each line
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) % 20 == 0)
                System.out.println(chars[i]);
            else 
                System.out.print(chars[i] + " ");
        }
    }
        /** Count the occurences of each letter*/
        public static int[] countLetters(char[] chars) {
            //Declare and create an array of 26 int
            int[] counts = new int[26];

            //For each lower case letter in the array, count it
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
                counts[chars[i] - 'a']++;

            return counts;
        }
        /**Display counts*/
        public static void displayCounts(int[] counts) {
            for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
                if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
                    System.out.print((counts[i] + " " + (char)(i + 'a')));
                else
                    System.out.print(counts[i] + " " + (char)(i + 'a') + " ");
            }
        }
}

        }
        /**Display counts*/
        public static void displayCounts(int[] counts) {
            for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
                if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
                    System.out.print((counts[i] + " " + (char)(i + 'a')));
                else
                    System.out.print(counts[i] + " " + (char)(i + 'a') + " ");
            }
        }
}
```

and here is the RandomCharacter.getRandomLowerCaseLetter(); class I am trying to call:

```
package randomcharacter;

/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class RandomCharacter {
        /**Generate a random character between ch1 and ch2**/


    public static char getRandomCharacter(char ch1, char ch2) {
        return (char)(ch1 + Math.random() * (ch2 - ch1 + 1));    
    }
    //Generate a lower case letter
    public static char getRandomLowerCaseLetter() {
        return getRandomCharacter('a', 'z');
    }
    //Generate an upper case letter
    public static char getRandomUpperCaseLetter() {
        return getRandomCharacter('A', 'B');
    }
    //Generate a random number
    public static char getRandomDigitCharacter() {
        return getRandomCharacter('0', '9');
    }
    //Generate a random character
    public static char getRandomCharacter() {
        return getRandomCharacter('\u0000', '\uFFFF');
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need to put the other class in `src/randomCharacter` in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

You should enter

```
package randomcharacter;
```

in your calling class which is - `CountLettersInArray`

Then only `RandomCharacter.getRandomLowerCaseLetter()` will be accesible.

I have checked your programs -

Your two classes will be respectively -

1>RandomCharacter.java

```
package randomcharacter;

/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class RandomCharacter {
        /**Generate a random character between ch1 and ch2**/


    public static char getRandomCharacter(char ch1, char ch2) {
        return (char)(ch1 + Math.random() * (ch2 - ch1 + 1));    
    }
    //Generate a lower case letter
    public static char getRandomLowerCaseLetter() {
        return getRandomCharacter('a', 'z');
    }
    //Generate an upper case letter
    public static char getRandomUpperCaseLetter() {
        return getRandomCharacter('A', 'B');
    }
    //Generate a random number
    public static char getRandomDigitCharacter() {
        return getRandomCharacter('0', '9');
    }
    //Generate a random character
    public static char getRandomCharacter() {
        return getRandomCharacter('\u0000', '\uFFFF');
    }
}
```

and

2> CountLettersInArray.java

```
package randomcharacter;

/**
*
* @author james
*/
public class CountLettersInArray {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Declare and create an array
       char[] chars = createArray();

       //Display the array
       System.out.println("The lowercase letters are:");
       displayArray(chars);

       //Count the occurences of each letter
       int[] counts = countLetters(chars);

       //Displahy counts
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("The occurences of each letter are:");
       displayCounts(counts);        
   }

   /**Create an array of characters**/
   public static char[] createArray() {
       //Declare an array of characters and create it
       char[] chars = new char[100];

       //Create lower case letters randomly and assign
       //them to the array
       for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
           chars[i] = RandomCharacter.getRandomLowerCaseLetter();

       //Return the array
       return chars;
   }

   public static void displayArray(char[] chars) {
       //Display characters in the array 20 on each line
       for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
           if ((i + 1) % 20 == 0)
               System.out.println(chars[i]);
           else 
               System.out.print(chars[i] + " ");
       }
   }
       /** Count the occurences of each letter*/
       public static int[] countLetters(char[] chars) {
           //Declare and create an array of 26 int
           int[] counts = new int[26];

           //For each lower case letter in the array, count it
           for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
               counts[chars[i] - 'a']++;

           return counts;
       }
       /**Display counts*/
       public static void displayCounts(int[] counts) {
           for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
               if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
                   System.out.print((counts[i] + " " + (char)(i + 'a')));
               else
                   System.out.print(counts[i] + " " + (char)(i + 'a') + " ");
           }
       }
}
```

which will display output like -

```
The lowercase letters are:
z n s q a m a h w f f o c e f q i m e g
i g w k p q x f g z l h r c d g a a y l
q z n b y k i w n b b s z a k e z o e x
g b p b l t d o c n l q m h p m c t y q
b y y r k x c t i m f o q i g o k w c w

The occurences of each letter are:
5 a 6 b 6 c 2 d 4 e 5 f 6 g 3 h 5 i 0 j5 k 4 l 5 m 4 n 5 o 3 p 7 q 2 r 2 s 3 t0 u 0 v 5 w 3 x 5 y 5 z
```

Hope, this solve your problem.

Comment: I just noticed there is no main method on the randomcharacter program, could that be my issue?

Comment: For whatever reason, I still can't get this program to work.  My book had me create the randomcharacter file, save it, then create the CountLettersInArray file.  When I attempt to run the CountLettersInArray file, the only error I have is the red line under RandomCharacter.  Should I make these two files into one for it to work?

Comment: No, make separate files - RandomCharacter.java and CountLettersInArray.java and put them in a package - randomcharacter

Comment: Got it, guess I must have missed that part in the NetBeans tutorial.  Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your first class is in the default package. Your second class is in package `randomcharacter`. Your second class should be in the directory `./randomcharacter` where `.` is the directory of your first class.

You should be able to see this visually in NetBeans under both the `Project` and the `Files` view.

Comment: I've tried going back, recompiling the random character program, selecting the CountLetterInArray project in the projects tab, selecting libraries, right click, add project, selecting the RandomCharacter project.  It still isn't importing the class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the RandomCharacter.getRandomLowerCaseLetter();

just use the Random class.

```
char[] chars = new char[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {

            Random random = new Random();

            char randomChar = (char) (random.nextInt(26) + 'a');

            chars[i] = randomChar;
        }
```

this code will solve your problem and give you the same  output as you needed.